# Convert a table of edge descriptions to a list of arrays containing trees

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, graph-theory

I've got two tables in Snowflake, which define a bunch of graphs. They look like this:

Node Table:

```
node    family   <other descriptive columns>  
A       1
B       1
C       1
D       1
E       1
F       1
G       1
H       1
I       2
J       2

etc...
```

Edge Table:

```
to   from
A        B
B        C
B        D
D        E
F        G
G        H

etc...
```

A family describes a collection of one or more related graphs; some of these may be a single graph, others may be several small graphs etc. The graphs are unidirectional and may have several branches/forks. There is currently no label for each of these graphs (that is, it needs to be inferred from the connections).

I'd like to create a table with a list of graphs in it, such as:

```
family   id    structure
1        1     [A -> B -> C, B -> D -> E]
1        2     [F -> G -> H] 
2 ... etc...
```

Where each row represents a set of connected nodes and the structure of that set and id is a new label for the graph object.

I've made some progress using recursive CTEs but hit a wall. Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we need to build the recursions.

```
WITH nodes(node, family) AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES
        ('A',1),
        ('B',1),
        ('C',1),
        ('D',1),
        ('E',1),
        ('F',1),
        ('G',1),
        ('H',1),
        ('I',2),
        ('J',2)
), edges(_from, _to) AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES
        ('A','B'),
        ('B','C'),
        ('B','D'),
        ('D','E'),
        ('F','G'),
        ('G','H')
), recursive_wrapper AS (
    WITH recur AS (
        -- Anchor Clause
        select
            family, 
            node, 
            node as tail, 
            array_construct(node) path, 
            1 as depth
        from nodes
        
        union all

        -- Recursive Clause
        select r.family,
            r.node,
            e._to as tail,
            ARRAY_APPEND(r.path, e._to) as path,
            r.depth + 1 as depth 
        from recur AS r
        join edges AS e
            on r.tail = e._from
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM recur
)
SELECT * 
FROM recursive_wrapper
WHERE node = 'A'
```

gives:

| FAMILY | NODE | TAIL | PATH | DEPTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | [ "A" ] | 1 |
| 1 | A | B | [ "A", "B" ] | 2 |
| 1 | A | C | [ "A", "B", "C" ] | 3 |
| 1 | A | D | [ "A", "B", "D" ] | 3 |
| 1 | A | E | [ "A", "B", "D", "E" ] | 4 |

Then we need to prune the sublimated rows (in above we want to remove depth 1,2,4 as they are sub parts of another row), we can do this by swapping from an array to a string for `path`

```
), recursive_wrapper AS (
    WITH recur AS (
        -- Anchor Clause
        select
            family, 
            node, 
            node as tail, 
            node::text path, /* this cast it to max size, verse the largest size of the input */
            1 as depth
        from nodes
        
        union all

        -- Recursive Clause
        select r.family,
            r.node,
            e._to as tail,
            r.path || '_' || e._to as path,
            r.depth + 1 as depth 
        from recur AS r
        join edges AS e
            on r.tail = e._from
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM recur
)
SELECT a.*
    ,b.path as b_path
    ,b.depth as b_depth
    ,startswith(b.path, a.path) as starts
    ,sum(iff(starts,1,0)) over(partition by a.family, a.node, a.path) as dominated_count
FROM recursive_wrapper as a
LEFT JOIN recursive_wrapper as b 
    ON a.family = b.family AND a.node = b.node AND a.depth < b.depth
WHERE a.node = 'A'
ORDER BY 1,2,4;
```

gives:

| FAMILY | NODE | TAIL | PATH | DEPTH | B_PATH | B_DEPTH | STARTS | DOMINATED_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | A | 1 | A_B | 2 | TRUE | 4 |
| 1 | A | A | A | 1 | A_B_C | 3 | TRUE | 4 |
| 1 | A | A | A | 1 | A_B_D | 3 | TRUE | 4 |
| 1 | A | A | A | 1 | A_B_D_E | 4 | TRUE | 4 |
| 1 | A | B | A_B | 2 | A_B_C | 3 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | A_B | 2 | A_B_D | 3 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | A_B | 2 | A_B_D_E | 4 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1 | A | C | A_B_C | 3 | A_B_D_E | 4 | FALSE | 0 |
| 1 | A | D | A_B_D | 3 | A_B_D_E | 4 | TRUE | 1 |
| 1 | A | E | A_B_D_E | 4 |  |  |  | 0 |

so we want to just keep those with a count of zero, which we can do in a QUALIFY

```
SELECT a.*
    --,b.path as b_path
    --,b.depth as b_depth
    --,startswith(b.path, a.path) as starts
    --,sum(iff(starts,1,0)) over(partition by a.family, a.node, a.path) as dominated_count

FROM recursive_wrapper as a
LEFT JOIN recursive_wrapper as b 
    ON a.family = b.family AND a.node = b.node AND a.depth < b.depth
WHERE a.node = 'A'
QUALIFY sum(iff(startswith(b.path, a.path),1,0)) over(partition by a.family, a.node, a.path) = 0
ORDER BY 1,2,4;
```

gives:

| FAMILY | NODE | TAIL | PATH | DEPTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C | A_B_C | 3 |
| 1 | A | E | A_B_D_E | 4 |

This will explode with loops, which we can protect against by put the array back, and checking for the value already being in the array

```
WITH nodes(node, family) AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES
        ('A',1),
        ('B',1),
        ('C',1),
        ('D',1),
        ('E',1),
        ('F',1),
        ('G',1),
        ('H',1),
        ('I',2),
        ('J',2)
), edges(_from, _to) AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES
        ('A','B'),
        ('B','C'),
        ('B','D'),
        ('D','E'),
        ('F','G'),
        ('G','H')
), recursive_wrapper AS (
    WITH recur AS (
        -- Anchor Clause
        select
            family, 
            node, 
            node as tail, 
            node::text path, /* this cast it to max size, verse the largest size of the input */
            array_construct(node) a_path, 
            1 as depth
        from nodes
        
        union all

        -- Recursive Clause
        select r.family,
            r.node,
            e._to as tail,
            r.path || '_' || e._to as path,
            ARRAY_APPEND(r.a_path, e._to) as a_path,
            r.depth + 1 as depth 
        from recur AS r
        join edges AS e
            on r.tail = e._from AND ARRAY_CONTAINS( e._to::variant , r.a_path ) = FALSE
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM recur
)
SELECT a.*
FROM recursive_wrapper as a
LEFT JOIN recursive_wrapper as b 
    ON a.family = b.family AND a.node = b.node AND a.depth < b.depth
QUALIFY sum(iff(startswith(b.path, a.path),1,0)) over(partition by a.family, a.node, a.path) = 0
ORDER BY 1,2,4;
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful answer laid out so clearly.

Comment: An additional challenge I have is that the trees don't start with the same node in every case - each node has a unique ID and in some cases, even within the same family, there may be multiple trees each starting with different nodes - some may start with 'A', some may start with 'F' etc.

Comment: Remove the “where node = a” i had meant to remove that. Bt left it there as it made the volume of output manageable.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've found this works if I change STARTSWITH to CONTAINS, but unfortunately my data is too big that the recursion works in O(n^{2}) time so takes too long. I'll need to take the data out of SQL for now. Thanks again!

Comment: It will still be n^2 outside sql. Unless you have extra information you will use to prune with.  At which point use the i. Sql.

Comment: Yep - but outside SQL I can model it as a set of network graphs and use graph operations to get the same outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
- Extract the two tables into your favorite programming language.
- Create a set of families
- Iterate F over family set
    - Iterate over rows in node table
         - If node belongs to F
              - Add node to vector
    - Construct empty adjacency matrix ( square 2D vector of size node vector size
    - Iterate N1 over node vector
          - Iterate N2 != N1 over node vector
                - IF N1-N2 in edge table
                       - Add to adjacency matrix
    - Iterate N1 over node vector
          - IF N1 has zero in-edges
               - Output tree rooted at N1
```

Comment: Thanks - agreed it would be much easier to do in something like Python, but given this data is something that is updated regularly, I'm naively hoping it's possible to do in pure SQL...

Comment: Python would be a terrible choice, far too slow.  You will need a compiled language, such as C++.  How frequent are your regular updates?  You can add a loop that checks every few seconds for an update and then sleeps if no update until the next check is due.